# Texture not mapping to square correctly WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, textures, webgl

For some reason why i map the texture to the boxes i have drawn on the 3d canvas it is not showing correctly, all i get is a blue box and not the full texture.

```
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment" type="text/javascript">
    precision mediump float;
    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

  uniform sampler2D uSampler;
    void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler, vec2(vTextureCoord.s, vTextureCoord.t));
    }
</script>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex" type="text/javascript">
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
    }
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var gl;
    var neheTexture;

    function initGL(canvas) {
        try {
            gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
            gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
            gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
        } catch (e) {
        }
        if (!gl) {
            alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
        }
    }

    function getShader(gl, id) {
        var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
        if (!shaderScript) {
            return null;
        }

        var str = "";
        var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
        while (k) {
            if (k.nodeType == 3) {
                str += k.textContent;
            }
            k = k.nextSibling;
        }

        var shader;
        if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
            shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
            shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
        gl.compileShader(shader);

        if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
            return null;
        }

        return shader;
    }

    var shaderProgram;

    function initShaders() {
        var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
        var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

        shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

        if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
            alert("Could not initialise shaders");
        }

        gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

        shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

        shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
        shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
    }

    var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
    var pMatrix = mat4.create();

    function setMatrixUniforms() {
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);
    }

    var squareVertexPositionBuffer;

    function initBuffers() {
        squareVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexPositionBuffer);
        vertices = [
             1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            -1.0, 1.0, 0.0,
             1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
            -1.0, -1.0, 0.0
        ];
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        squareVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
        squareVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 4;
    }

    var z = -50.0;
    var eye = vec3.create([0, 0, z]);  // negation of actual eye position

    var pvMatrix = mat4.create();

    var pvMatrixInverse = mat4.create();

    function drawScene() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("MyCanvas");
        var widthamount = Math.round(canvas.width/20);
        var heightamount = Math.round(canvas.height / 20);


        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        mat4.perspective(90, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 3000.0, pMatrix);

        mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

        // calculate the view transform mvMatrix, and the projection-view matrix pvMatrix
        mat4.translate(mvMatrix, eye);
        mat4.multiply(pMatrix, mvMatrix, pvMatrix);

        var startHeight = -((heightamount * 2.1) / 2);
        var startWidth = -((widthamount * 2.1) / 2);

        mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [startWidth, startHeight, 0.0]);
        for (i = 0; i < heightamount; ++i) {
            for (q = 0; q < widthamount; ++q) {
                mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [2.1, 0.0, 0.0]);
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexPositionBuffer);
                gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, squareVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

                gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
                gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, neheTexture);
                gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);

                setMatrixUniforms();
                gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, squareVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
            }
            mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [-(widthamount*2.1), 2.1, 0.0]);
        }
    }

    function webGLStart() {
        resizeCanvas();
        var canvas = document.getElementById("MyCanvas");
        initGL(canvas);
        initShaders();
        initBuffers();
        initTexture();

        gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

        tick();
    }



     function resizeCanvas() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("MyCanvas");
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        //drawScene();
    }


    function handleLoadedTexture(texture) {
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
    }



    function initTexture() {
        neheTexture = gl.createTexture();
        neheTexture.image = new Image();
        neheTexture.image.onload = function () {
            handleLoadedTexture(neheTexture)
        }

        neheTexture.image.src = "nehe.gif";
    }

</script>
```

Image for texture looks like a full texture https://github.com/gpjt/webgl-lessons/blob/master/lesson05/nehe.gif

However boxes turn out to show like a blue box, i need 10 rep to put images :(((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no texture coordinates.

You need to set up a buffer with texture coordinates

```
 squareTextureCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareTextureCoordBuffer);
 texcoords = [
       1.0, 1.0, 
       0.0, 1.0, 
       1.0, 0.0, 
       0.0, 0.0, 
 ];
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(texcoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
```

Then you're going to need to look up the location of the where the shader wants the texture coordinates

```
textureCoordAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord");
```

And set up that attribute

```
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordAttribute);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(textureCoordAttribute, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

Also while we're at it there's a bunch of minor things about the code you might want to consider

1. The code is turning on attributes in initShaders but if you have multiple shaders you'll need to turn on/off attributes in your draw call
2. The code is assigning properties to WebGL objects as in `shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = ...` and `squareVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;` but if you ever decide to handle WebGLContextLost events that code will break because `gl.createBuffer` and `gl.createShader` will return `null` which means your code will be doing `null.itemSize = 3` for example. It's better to make your own objects with WebGL as in `var buffer = { id: gl.createBuffer(), itemSize: 3, ...};` so that if you do decide to handle WebGLContextLost events your code won't break.
3. The code is setting the attributes and uniforms for every face of the cube. But since  they're the same for every face it would be more efficient to set the ones that don't change just once outside the loop.
4. The stuff about `gl.viewportWidth` and `gl.viewportHeight` is semi confusing since it makes it look like `viewportWidth` and `viewportHeight` are official parts of WebGL even though they are not. On top of that if you have a canvas that scales or changes shape they'll get out of sync which it does in `resizeCanvas`. Better just to use `gl.canvas.width`, `gl.canvas.height` directly or even better `gl.drawBufferWidth`, `gl.drawingBufferHeight`
5. The size the canvas is displayed is separate from its resolution. It's more appropriate to set your aspect ratio to the size it is displayed. In other words `mat4.perspective(90, gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight, 0.1, 3000.0, pMatrix);` will make it render in the correct aspect ratio regardless of the resolution of the canvas.